# Not sure how to fix error 404 github pages

Tags: reactjs, github

Hi I've recently deployed my react project for a uni assignment however once its finished and it says Published when I open the link my website doesnt open but just says 404 There isnt a Github pages site here. When I open the developer tools I can see an error saying

gusdesign01.github.io/:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Im not entirely sure what Ive done wrong here and unsure how to fix, any help would be greatly appreciated!

link to the github page - https://gusdesign01.github.io/FutureSportsSoccer/

link to github repository - https://github.com/gusDesign01/future-Sports.git

Comment: The GH Page URL is: https://gusdesign01.github.io/future-Sports/. Similarly your file paths should start with `future-Sports/` instead of `FutureSportsSoccer/`.

Comment: So your saying I need to change https://gusdesign01.github.io/FutureSportsSoccer/ to https://gusdesign01.github.io/Future-Sports?